# How to compare data any field of two table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two tables with same columns. 
Table A have `ID, Name, Des, Status` and 
Table B have `ID, Name, Des, Status`.
I want to compare data any field of Table B with Table A, except column `ID` because same.

[image]

As same picture above, when `FETCH` data of Table B, detect data of ID `ID001` and `ID003` not same, idea of my mind same

```
IF (SELECT COUNT (SELECT * FROM TABLE A RIGHT JOIN TABLE B ON A.ID = B.ID) != 0)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'BLAH BLAH, NOT SAME'
END
```

If you have idea or solution, share for me, Thank you so much.

Comment: Right joins tend to be the exception when writing sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CHECKSUM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/checksum-transact-sql) or [BINARY_CHECKSUM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/binary-checksum-transact-sql):

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b ON b.ID = a.ID 
WHERE CHECKSUM(b.Name, b.Des, b.Status) <> CHECKSUM(a.Name, a.Des, a.Status)
```

See also [this link](http://cc.davelozinski.com/sql/sql-fastest-way-to-compare-multiple-column-values). It should be faster then multiple OR conditions.

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*)     
    FROM TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b ON b.ID = a.ID 
    WHERE BINARY_CHECKSUM(b.Name, b.Des, b.Status)
       <> BINARY_CHECKSUM(a.Name, a.Des, a.Status)
    >0
 PRINT 'Not the same.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not too much clear how do you want to show your differences, this is one approach:

```
SELECT A.ID, 
(CASE WHEN A.Name <> B.Name THEN 'Diff Name' ELSE '') NameCompare,
(CASE WHEN A.Des <> B.Des THEN 'Diff Des' ELSE '') DESCompare,
(CASE WHEN A.Status <> B.Status THEN 'Diff Status' ELSE '') StatusCompare
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple join

To get all different rows, you can say:

```
select a.*, b.*
from TableA a inner join TableB b on b.ID = a.ID 
where b.Name <> a.Name or b.Des <> a.Des or b.Status <> a.Status
```